# Conexiion a bases de datos mysql desde HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

Buenas tardes me encuentro con el siguiente error, quiero obtener un resultado de una consulta de SQL hacia una DB local realice un archivo php con la clase y su funcion, y realice un archi html para que me la presente pero me indica error 
//arhivo php para la conexion

```
<?php

       class conexion {

        function restantes(){

                $enlace = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'admin');
                if (!$enlace) {
                  die('No se pudo conectar : ' . mysql_error());
                    }


                    $bd_seleccionada = mysql_select_db('Kupon', $enlace);
                    if (!$bd_seleccionada) {
                         die ('No se puede usar Kupon : ' .mysql_error());
                            }

            $query = ' SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta ' ;
            $resultado = mysql_query($query);

            while ($fila = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {
            echo "$fila [meta_value]";

            }

            }
}

     ?>
```

**en HTML lo mando a llamar asi**

```
<?php
include("conexion.php");
$enlace = new  conexion();
$enlace ->restantes();


 ?>
```

grcias

Comment: no deberías estar usando `mysql_*` functions puesta estan obsoletas y son inseguras

Comment: Que recomiendas?

Comment: que si esta en su posibilidades migres a `mysqli_*` e idealmente `PDO`

Comment: gracias buscare informacion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
$s="localhost";
$bd="Kupon";
$u="root";
$p="admin";

$conexion=new mysqli($s, $u, $p, $bd);

if ($conexion -> connect_errno ) {


    echo "no Conectado";

}
else {


    $sql= "SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta where  meta_key = '_stock' and post_id = 427 "; 
    $query=$conexion->query($sql); 
    if($query->num_rows>0){ 
    while($r=$query->fetch_array()){ 
    echo $r["meta_value"]; 
    echo "<br>";
    }
    }else{ 
    echo "No hay resultados";
    }
}

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ];
$db = new PDO($dsn, $db_user, $db_pass, $opt);
try{
 $db = new PDO($host, $db_user, $db_pass, $opt);
}
catch( PDOException $Exception ) {
 echo $Exception->getMessage();
?>